# BeautifulSoup4 - Requests - How to find TBODY classes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve data from the following website: http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-amplos/indice-ibovespa-ibovespa-composicao-da-carteira.htm

Why the following code doesn't return anything?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-amplos/indice-ibovespa-ibovespa-composicao-da-carteira.htm').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

soup.find('tbody')
```

Sample of the elements of the website:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="rgRow GridBovespaItemStyle" id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00__0" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
        <td class="rgSorted" align="left">
                                <span id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00_ctl04_lblCodigo">ABEV3</span>
                            </td><td align="left">
                                <span id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00_ctl04_lblAcao">AMBEV S/A</span>
                            </td><td align="left">
                                <span id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00_ctl04_lblTipo">ON</span>
                            </td><td class="text-right">
                                <span id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00_ctl04_lblQtdeTeorica_Formatada">4.354.228.928</span>
                            </td><td class="text-right">
                                <span id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_grdResumoCarteiraTeorica_ctl00_ctl04_lblPart_Formatada">3,003</span>
                            </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Expected Output - The content of all table columns and rows:

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output? you just need tbody classes?

Comment: Hello @Tasnuva, I've just updated the topic with the expected output.

Comment: hey have you checked the url? does the site down or what? I can't access the url.

Comment: @Tasnuva, it is working fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to actually loads a iframe with the table in it. The URL of the document in the frame is http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/ResumoCarteiraTeorica.aspx?Indice=IBOV&idioma=pt-br If you use that URL you'll see the `<tbody>`